# Bonita BPM do not wait for Bonita's function end

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, business-process-management, bonita

I am creating a JAVA application that use Bonita BPM API, i am using a simple code like this:

```
ProcessInstance processInstance = App.getProcessAPI().startProcess(App.getProcessDefinitionId(),App.getListOperation(), listVariablesSerializable);
processId = processInstance.getId();
Thread.sleep(1000);
App.getBuilder().filter(ProcessInstanceSearchDescriptor.STARTED_BY, App.getAPISession().getUserId());
App.setPendingTasks(0, 30, null);
```

This code start a new process and set the new tasks to the user. But only works with `Thread.sleep(1000)` because `App.setPendingTasks(0, 30, null)` doesn't want to wait for `App.getProcessAPI().startProcess(App.getProcessDefinitionId(),App.getListOperation(), listVariablesSerializable);` to end.

I know that `Thread.sleep(1000)` is not a good programming practice and I need another solution please.

Comment: Have you looked at the Bonita BPM API documentation and examples? https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/?page=manage-a-process

Comment: Yes, I did. (Copy - paste)

Comment: It works perfect in debug mode. but in a normal start y need a sleep function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obviously experiencing a race condition between when the instance is created and the details of it are persisted to the database.

Since you have the ProcessInstance returned from the start command.
Why don't you simply retrieve the activities (tasks) for the instance directly using the ProcessAPI?

```
List<ActivityInstance> activities = App.getProcessAPI().getActivities(processId, 0, 10);
```

This API should use the current process state and not query the database.